# Why is the plural of "aircraft" not "aircrafts"?

Tags: etymology, nouns, grammatical-number, irregular

I came along [this sentence](http://www.euronews.com/2014/03/10/hijacking-not-being-discounted-as-search-for-missing-malaysia-airlines-jet-/):

> Today, we have used a large number of assets, comprising of **34 aircraft**, 40 ships, hundreds of men, thousands of man-hours has been deployed

I consulted dictionaries and [forum threads](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/aircraft.2048854/) that explained that *aircraft*, just like *sheep*, builds its plural without an *-s*.

For *sheep*, however, that [can be explained](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50309/why-is-sheep-the-same-when-talking-about-one-or-more-than-one#answer-50312) by its evolution from an old word. Not so for *aircraft*, which is a relatively new word with no such legacy. I found it stated that it is simply a concatenation of *air* and *craft*.

I found [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46824/why-does-the-incorrect-plural-aircrafts-seem-to-be-occurring-more-often) about the possible increasing usage of *aircrafts* (probably among non-native speakers), but it didn't explain the etymology and I found nothing else to explain it.

So, what is the explanation for the plural of *aircraft* not being *aircrafts*? Does it come from [*craft*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/craft) used as a mass noun? If so, what would be the meaning conveyed by that?

Comment: If you look in the dictionary, the word [*craft*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/craft) meaning *boat* has a notation of "*plural usually* **craft**". (While the plural for the meaning *occupation or trade* is *crafts*.)

Comment: @PeterShor Yes - exactly my thought. *A lot of small craft were bobbing up and down in the water*.

Comment: @PeterShor I have seen it, and it is why I asked about "its non plural form",  I was refering to this meaning and asking why it has been used more that the meaning of object created

Comment: This dictionary from 1735 hyphenates *small-craft*. The hyphenation may provide a clue. Compare *small-pox*.  https://books.google.com/books?id=l0JgAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT746&dq=%22small+craft%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QTCRVY7pGIf0yATCz4CoAQ&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22small%20craft%22&f=false

Comment: English is like that for hysterical reasons.

Comment: I don't think there's any rhyme or reason for irregular words like this. They just happen.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plurals#Irregular_plurals

Comment: Note that "comprising of" in your quoted text is incorrect usage.  It should be simply **comprising** or else **composed of**.  Interestingly, we have encountered this same sentence before, in connection with its other grammatical flaws. Oh, and BTW we say "came across" a sentence, not "came along".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is because *craft* is a collective term and *OED* mentions that it might be originated as an elliptical expression. *Craft* itself is used as *aircraft* as well. *OED* includes the following explanation for the fifth definition of *craft*:

> **V.** Applied to boats, ships, and fishing requisites.
>
> These uses were probably colloquial with watermen, fishers, and seamen some time before they appeared in print, so that the history is not evidenced; but the expression is probably elliptical, **sense 9   being = vessels of small craft**, i.e. small trading vessels, or of small seaman's art, and **sense 10   = requisites of the fisherman's craft**. It is not impossible that the latter was the earlier: cf. quot. 1704 at sense 10. **The want in English of any general collective term for all sorts of ‘vessels for water carriage’ naturally made craft a useful stop-gap.**

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

For reference<sup>[OED]</sup>:

> **9.**
>    **a.** collect. (*const.* as *pl.*) Vessels or boats.
>   (a) originally only in small craft *n.*
>   (b) Hence, without *small*, in same sense; later, in the general sense of vessels of all kinds for water carriage and transport.
>   **b.** (with *a* and *pl.*) A small vessel or boat; any sailing or floating vessel.
>   **c.** An aircraft or spacecraft.
>
> ---
>
> **10.** *collect.* Implements used in catching or killing fish; in mod. use chiefly in Whale-fishery: see quot. 1887.
>
> *Craft*, is a Sea word signifying all manner of Lines, Nets, Hooks, &c. which serve for Fishing; and because those that use the Fishing Trade use Small Vessels..they call all such little Vessels *Small Craft*.
>
> <sub>1704   J. Harris *Lexicon Technicum*</sub>
>
> ---
>
> The harpoons, hand-lances, and boat-spades, are usually called ‘craft’, and the other implements ‘gear’.
>
> <sub>1887   G. B. Goode *Fisheries U.S.: Hist. & Methods* II. 241</sub>

However, *OED* mentions that the plural form *aircrafts* is rare and there is one citation that *aircrafts* is used:

> His world-famed aircrafts.
>
> <sub>1903   Aeronaut. Jrnl. 7 81/1</sub>

*OED* also adds that the word can be understood, esp. when used in the plural, to include other kinds of heavier-than-air machine, such as helicopters. The word is often preferred to aeroplane or airplane in official and military contexts:

> Will you please make the following terminology effective in all British official correspondence: For ‘aeroplane’ the word ‘aircraft’ should be used.
>
> <sub>1943   W. S. Churchill *Telegram* 15 June in *Second World War* (1952) V. 566</sub>

Comment: @ermanen You think it is only based on *craft* meaning *"ship"* without plural? I don't think in my example the `34 aircraft` can be a mass noun

Comment: @YohannV.: It is originated from there and it became a collective term. Then it is applied to waterctraft, aircraft etc. It is why the plural form is the same but as I said, it is rarely used as *aircrafts* also.

Comment: @ermanen I have read that the *aircrafts* form is used by non-native and is not correct.

Comment: @YohannV.: Where did you read? *Aircrafts* is not preferred and probably used in technical contexts only.

Comment: @ermanen [In the link I gave](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46824/why-does-the-incorrect-plural-aircrafts-seem-to-be-occurring-more-often) and [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/aircraft) has nothing about *"aircrafts"*

Comment: @YohannV.: *OED* is more comprehensive but not accessible without subscription.

Comment: @ermanen Wiktionary also : `The nonstandard plural form aircrafts is in use among non-native speakers of English.` But I know this source is not judged as valid on this forum. ;)

Answer (score 4):

The word *craft* is obviously related to German *Kraft* (plural *Kräfte*), meaning *might, power* (or in physics *force*). It still had this meaning in Middle English. [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=craft) explains the connection to boats:

> Use for "small boat" is first recorded 1670s, probably from a phrase similar to *vessels of small craft* and referring either to the trade they did or the seamanship they required, or perhaps it preserves the word in its original sense of "power."

As an ellipsis for "vessel[s] of small craft", a (singular and) plural word "small craft" makes perfect sense. Once the ellipsis has become a fixed expression whose origin people don't remember, *small* will easily be re-interpreted as referring to physical size (which, after all, is strongly associated with a boat's power), so that the rarely used "[vessels of] great craft" will look irregular and "large craft" will be said instead. At this point it was only natural to drop the adjectives and use *craft* as a collective term for boats which, however, continued and continues to be used also for singulars. Then the apparent singular form of the word facilitates regularisation to *crafts* when used as a plural. Language change takes centuries, so the last step is where we are now.

I have extrapolated all of this from the one sentence quoted above without checking any further sources, so the actual historical details may have been slightly different.

PS: I am not claiming that when people started using "small craft" for boats the word *craft* was still used in the original sense of *power*. It may not be known what the precise original meaning of "small craft" was, and I certainly don't know. It seems possible to me that the *power* meaning of *craft* survived for longer in nautical terminology, both because such terminology is often a bit detached from evolutions in the remainder of the language, and because the seafaring part of the population presumably had more contact with German-speakers. But it's also possible that "small craft" originally referred to boats of little workmanship and that the sense shifted later.

Comment: I my view a nice theory, complicated and not very convincing. It is the view of etymonline/OED where there is no astonishmemt about the semantic discrepancy between power and vessel. Instead one tries to  wipe away this discrepancy and offers views how "power" might have developed the sense of vessel.

Comment: @rogermue The obvious explanation for this approach by the experts would be that they have a good overview of possible candidates unrelated to *craft* in other European languages, and there aren't any. Besides, this kind of meaning shift happens all the time even today. E.g. *burg[h]er* originally referred to a citizen of a town; now it refers to meat, especially embedded in bread (via 'Hamburg steaks' and fast food).

Comment: The experts say "probably"  as to the meaning of boat. But why should a  word that means boat not have a normal plural?  Don't overestimate what you find in etymological dictionaries.

Comment: Experts are used to being proved wrong later in situations where they were just speculating, so they don't claim an etymology as fact unless the entire chain of changes is documented with each link not just plausible but fitting a well established pattern (i.e. lots of other words changed the same way). A word meaning *boat* doesn't have a normal plural, for instance, if it came up in the same way as *small fry* for fish.

Comment: @HansAdler What happens when you serve more that one plate of *small fry* ? `3 small fr{y/ies} for the [table] 7 !` ?

Comment: @YohannV.: I have to take that example back anyway, as it turns out that it isn't related to frying, as I had thought. I am sure there are other examples that actually work, but I can't think of one right now and I don't know how to search for them.

Comment: @HansAdler But what would happen if it was? How would you have turned the sentence?

Comment: @YohannV.: The way I envisaged it (fry = frying goods), it would not have occurred in such a context, and certainly not with a plural. But a glance into the OED has made me wiser.